# Using progress bar in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have sample code below, to use with progress bar.  I need to display progress with each item of loop (percentage and bar both)

```
For i = 0 To 200000
            ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
        Next
```

I have tried everything (background workers etc.) but could not figure it out.

I request someone to write me complete code (backgroundworkder, Cross Threading and whatever) and help me make it run.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: That's just not possible, ListBox is not thread-safe.  Just don't create horrible UI like that, compare to the way Google displays hundreds of thousands of search hits.

Comment: _I request someone to write me complete code_ I wonder why this question hasn't been burned down with green fire...

Answer (score 0):

Here you are, but don't forget that this is not a good idea:

```
Dim max As Integer = 200000
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.ProgressBar1.Maximum = max
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    For i = 1 To max
        BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    Dim i = e.ProgressPercentage
    ProgressBar1.Value = i
    ListBox1.Items.Add(i)
    'ListBox1.SelectedIndex = i - 1
End Sub
```